# Database-like basic use

Tags: database, r, dataframe

I would like to use R for basic database purpose with two data frames: the first data frame is a list of individuals with different features:

```
data = data.frame("individual"=c("Steve","Bob","Simon","Lisa"),
                  "feature1"=c(1,2,2,3),
                  "feature2"=c(3,4,1,NA))
```

the second data frame has features descritions:

```
description = data.frame("feature"=c(1,2,3,4,NA), 
                         "label"=c("foot","golf","curling","ski","No answer"))
```

My goal is to make a third data frame with the individuals names followed by their features descriptions:

```
Steve foot curling
Bob   golf ski
```

and so on...

Comment: [Deleting](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20947409/324364) and reposting your question is not how to go about this. I appreciate that you added data to your question, but StackOverflow generally isn't keen on questions that are little more than a description of a problem and the expectation of a solution. If **you** have a partial solution that isn't working, we'd be happy to help. Otherwise, this question still needs more work.

Comment: I agree this question could use some work. But to answer your question, try using the `merge` function. You'll have to do it twice, once for "feature1" and again for "feature2". However, I'm not sure how to hand the `NA` value with this approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this task, `match` can be used.

```
cbind(data[1], as.data.frame(lapply(data[-1], function(x) 
                              description$label[match(x, description$feature)])))

  individual feature1  feature2
1      Steve     foot   curling
2        Bob     golf       ski
3      Simon     golf      foot
4       Lisa  curling No answer
```

Answer (score 4):

**sqldf** Try this three way join:

```
library(sqldf)

data[is.na(data)] <- "NA"
description[is.na(description)] <- "NA"

sqldf("select d1.individual, d2.label, d3.label
        from data d1 
        left join description d2 on d1.feature1 = d2.feature
        left join description d3 on d1.feature2 = d3.feature"
)
```

The output is:

```
  individual   label     label
1      Simon    golf      foot
2      Steve    foot   curling
3        Bob    golf       ski
4       Lisa curling No answer
```

**subscripting**

This solution assumes we have run the two `<- "NA"` lines above.

```
labels <- with(description, setNames(label, feature))
with(data, 
  data.frame(individual, labels[feature1], labels[feature2], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
)
```

which gives the output:

```
   individual labels.feature1. labels.feature2.
3       Steve             foot          curling
4         Bob             golf              ski
1       Simon             golf             foot
NA       Lisa          curling        No answer
```

*REVISED:*

- Use left join.
- Handle NAs as regular values.
- Add second solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun a third approach using `plyr` and `reshape2`

```
require(reshape2)
require(plyr)
dcast(join(melt(data, id = "individual", value.name = "feature"), description),
      individual ~ variable, value.var = "label")

  individual feature1  feature2
1        Bob     golf       ski
2       Lisa  curling No answer
3      Simon     golf      foot
4      Steve     foot   curling
```